# EWS new-email Push Notifications for iOS and Android apps

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am looking to develop a mail app that supports both On-Prem Exchange server and Office365. In order to have real-time notifications whenever new emails come into users' mailbox, Exchange Web Service(EWS) push notification seems to be the only option for me. Since I want the app to be able to notify users even when it gets killed or backgrounded, the push notifications have to be sent through Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for Android and Apple Push Notification Service (APNS).

From what I have noticed, EWS does not provide any API to support sending notifications through FCM/APNS. Here is my questions:

1. Is EWS the really the only option for me to get new-email notifications (need to support both on-prem Exchange and Office365)?
2. When using EWS, besides hosting a listener server to direct notifications to FCM/APNS, is there any other approach I can use to implement the push notification?
3. Is there any third party push notification service supporting Exchange in terms of listening notifications and directing it through FCM/APNS?

Since hosting my own listener server requires a lot of back end work and will introduce scaling issues, I just wonder if there is an alternative/work around to make my mail app having real-time new email notification all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. EWS is the only option that I know will work for on-prem and O365.  There is also a REST API, but I've no idea whether it supports notifications.  MSFT has recently announced that EWS will eventually be superseded by the Graph API, but I have no idea what state that API is in right now, especially regarding older versions of on-prem Exchange.
2. You could opt for Streaming Notifications and avoid the HTTP listener.  In fact streaming is the most practical way to support notifications in O365 because is is firewall-friendly.
3. None that I am aware of.